# I want you to speak English / that you'll speak English / that you speak English

Tags: sentence-choice

My friend just started to learn English and I want to listen to him speaking English. My question is what is the best / correct way to tell him it out of the following three choices (or more others that I didn't mention):

1) I **want you to speak** English (optional: already).

2) I **want that you will speak** English (already).

3) I **want that you speak** English (already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I want you to speak English" is the correct version.

See the Cambridge Dictionary entry for [*want*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/common-verbs/want):

> > Warning:
>   We don’t use *want* with a *that*-clause:
>   *I **want** you to tidy your room before the visitors come.*
>   Not: <strike>I want that you tidy your room</strike> ...

Comment: +1 for the answer. It means that I shouldn't say "I want **that** he'll come here."? ( and I should say "I want he'll come here". No way that I can use "that" (except for demonstrative, of course) after want?

Comment: You need to use the object pronoun: I want him to come here. And thanks to the person who edited the link. I haven't worked out how to link properly yet.