# "I don't want that he becomes like me"; How to explain to a student why the grammar is wrong

Tags: grammar

So my Japanese student made this sentence:

> I don't want that he becomes like me.

I corrected it to:

> I don't want him to become like me.

but he doesn't understand why I removed **that**. How can I explain the reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want you to speak English / that you'll speak English / that you speak English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174446/i-want-you-to-speak-english-that-youll-speak-english-that-you-speak-english) IMHO this isn't a matter of "grammatical rules" as such - it's just that idiomatically we don't usually use a ***that- clause*** after ***to want***.

Comment: ...as pointed out [here](https://archive.org/stream/grammaroflatemod05poutuoft/grammaroflatemod05poutuoft_djvu.txt) - *it would require extensive reading to find a fairly large number of sentences with **to want** followed by a **subordinate statement***. But such sentences do exist, and they're not inherently ungrammatical - just non-idiomatic today.

Comment: Note that you have done more than just remove *that*. You have also changed *becomes* to *become*. It makes sense to do so because of the new construction without *that*. But is part of the confusion over *that he becomes* versus *that he become*?

Answer (score 1):

***She did not want that Harry should quarrel with his aunt for her sake.***

Thackeray, *The Virginians*, 1857-1859.

What your student said was not ungrammatical. But it does smack of the nineteenth century.  In the comments above there is a reference to the Cambridge Dictionary that clearly says we do not follow *want* with a subordinate clause beginning with *that*.